# QUndoStack rollback without possibility of redo()

Tags: qt

I need to rollback one (or possibly more) commands from `QUndoStack` by undoing them, but then I need to disable redoing them again. In other words, if I have commands `A`, `B` and `C` in the undo stack and then rollback `C`, I need `C` to be undone (which is easy) but I need `B` to be the last one (top-most) in the stack so that the user cannot trigger redoing `C` again (i.e. `C` should be gone for good). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you subclass QUndoStack and then make the redo() slot private? Also modify the CanRedo() function to return false.